# Using Cordova-Plugin-FCMNotification I can get only token and no messages

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using this plugin in my ionic 1 project.
Follow what author wrote [here](https://github.com/LokeshPatel/Cordova-Plugin-FCMNotification).

I can get token from Google Firebase when i run my app on device, but I don't understand how register and get messages and push notifications.. 
Anyone have examples on how get push notifications directly from Google Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with the plugin [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm), with this plugin I used the code below to receive push notifications,the plugin documentation, you will need to download the file google-services.json and copy it to your android platform , make sure you have the following installed on you sdk, the documentation on the plugin has a lot of detail

- Android Support Library version 23 or greater
- Android Support Repository version 20 or greater
- Google Play Services version 27 or greater
- Google Repository version 22 or greater

```html
FCMPlugin.getToken(
  function (token) {
    console.log(token);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
  }
);

FCMPlugin.onNotification(
  function(data){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    if(data.wasTapped){
      console.log("=====================alert received on device tray and tapped by the user================"+JSON.stringify(data));
     
    }else{
      console.log("=====================alert received when app is open================"+JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  },
  function(msg){
    console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
  },
  function(err){
    console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
  }
);
```